# Trouble bridging two Ethernet connections on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, home-networking, network-adapter, bridging

My Setup:

- Dell PowerEdge 2800, Ubuntu Server 12.04, 2 Ethernet ports
- Dell XPS, Windows 7 Home Edition, 1 Ethernet port

Router <--- eth0 ---> PowerEdge <--- eth1 ---> XPS

the objective here is to set up a bridge that shares the internet connection from eth0  to eth1

what I have tried:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 down
sudo ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0 down
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth1
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo ifconfig eth1 up
sudo ifconfig br0 up
```

After I do this, I try to `ping 8.8.8.8` and it comes up saying destination host unreachable. I'm new to Ubuntu networking so I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Questions on Linux and IP/routing should include at least the output of `ip address` and `ip route` or the relevant parts of those and information whether there was something interesting in the logs. Using `ifconfig` for testing stuff is a bit of a magic nowadays as it's development doesn't follow that of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Now the bridge and eth0 and eth1 should be ignored by NetworkManager. If after reboot you type ifconfig and there is an IP in eth0, uninstall NetworkManager and reboot again.

Comment: It's also good to check using `nmcli dev`.